# AWS Lambda Error: Cannot find module 'stripe' Require stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, stripe-payments, aws-amplify

I am trying to integrate Stripe into a React Native app with an AWS Amplify backend.

My schema.graphql includes two types

```
type Mutation {
  createPaymentIntent(amount: Int!): PaymentIntent! @function(name: "createPaymentIntent-${env}")
}

type PaymentIntent {
  clientSecret: String!
}
```

The index.js of the function requires stripe with a secret key.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(<secret.key>)

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const { typeName, arguments } = event;

    if (typeName !== 'Mutation') {
        throw new Error('Request is not a mutation');
    }

    if (!arguments?.amount) {
        throw new Error('Amount argument is required');
    }

    // create payment intent
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: arguments.amount,
        currency: 'usd'
    });

    return {
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    }
};
```

After running amplify push, when I try to run this mutation in AWS AppSync I am able to select the mutation.

```
mutation MyMutation {
  createPaymentIntent(amount: 10) {
    clientSecret
  }
}
```

It returns an error.

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createPaymentIntent"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Lambda:Unhandled",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

I already tried to remove and re-add the function. Also I ran yarn add stripe inside the function folder. My package.json in the function folder looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "createPaymentIntent",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "stripe":"^8.209.0"
  }
}
```

The expected behavior would be returning a client_secret.

Comment: The dependencies of my lambda functions look slightly different: ```{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "latest",
    "otherDependency": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92"
  }
}```. I don't know why it won't format properly, but I have a regular ```dependencies``` in addition to ```devDependencies```.

Comment: Thanks for this hint @man517. Managed to solve this by moving all devDependecies to dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was the package.json.

I managed to get it working by moving all devDependencies to dependencies. I remember trying this before but it didn't work since I populated both devDependencies and dependencies with the same packages. Working code looks like this now:

```
{
  "name": "createPaymentIntent",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.4.0",
    "stripe": "^8.209.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```