# Stripe module is not being found in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I have an app with an Amplify backend and I am getting an error when calling my Lambda:

"Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js"

I have installed stripe and see it in my dependencies from the main folder but not in the dependencies for my function. I tried to install stripe in my functions folder with no change. I am using React 17.0.2. The stripe version is 9.6.0.

I found a post with a similar problem but they were already able to install stripe: [AWS Lambda Error: Cannot find module 'stripe' Require stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459260/aws-lambda-error-cannot-find-module-stripe-require-stack)

My Lambda:

```html
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new aws.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});
const stripe = require('stripe')('secret key');

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */


exports.handler = async (event) => {

    try {
        const tableName = process.env.tableName
        const {username, email} = event.arguments.input

        const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
            type: 'express',
            email: `${email}`,
            metadata: {user: `${username}`}
        });

        console.log("Account creation response: ", account)
        console.log("Account id: ", account.id)

        // store the Stripe account id in DBB
        let ddbParams = {
            Item: {
                'stripe_id': `${account.id}`
            },
            TableName: tableName
        }
        
        try {
            await ddb.putItem(ddbParams).promise()
            console.log("Successfully updated stripe_id field")
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Storing to DB error: ", err)
        }

        const accountId = account.id

        const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
            account: accountId,
            //Swap for live website
            refresh_url: 'http://localhost:3000/profile',
            return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/listingform',
            type: 'account_onboarding',
          });

          console.log('Account link response :', accountLink)

          return accountLink
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }

};
```

My package.json in my functions folder:

```html
{
  "name": "createStripeConnectAccount",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92"
  }
}
```

**UDPATE**:
I managed to install stripe and have it as a dependency but I still get the same error.

My package.json now looks like this:

```html
{
  "name": "createStripeConnectAccount",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "save": "^2.5.0",
    "stripe": "^9.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the solution found by that SO? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71465800/3631795

Comment: Yes, but manually writing in the dependancy doesn't do anything.  Stripe doesn't show up as a dependency in the package.json of my function folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to first install Stripe in the src folder of the function. This didn't show up in the external terminal I had opened so I had to right click on the src folder and open a terminal in there. Then run npm install.

Keeping this question up for any other new developers or people new to AWS.

Comment: You can close the question by accepting your own answer. Your question will be still visible for other developers when they search for the issue, so no worry about that. The best practise is to close question once they are properly answered.